# Powershell Export-Csv -Append in new column

Tags: powershell

Just want to ask how to Export the data in existing CSV file in new column. I have this following code.

```
$Ex=Compare-Object $ImportWin7 $Importafipd1 -includeequal 

$Ex | Select-Object SideIndicator | Export-Csv -Append -Force  -NoTypeInformation "C:\NotBackedUp\EndpointAudit\Win7machinetest2.csv"
```

but  it appears that the Data from  $EX was appended not on the first row of the column.

Comment: Consider adding some sample data that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: You can't just add an additional column to existing csv document. You would want recreate it again with required number of columns.

Answer (score 3):

You can't just add an additional column to existing csv document. You would want to recreate it again with number of columns you need. Like so:

```
$ExistingCSV = Import-Csv "C:\NotBackedUp\EndpointAudit\Win7machinetest2.csv"

$Ex=Compare-Object $ImportWin7 $Importafipd1 -includeequal | Select-Object SideIndicator

$obj = @()
$i = 0

foreach ($row in $ExistingCSV)
{
    $item = New-Object PSObject -ArgumentList $row
    $item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty extra_column -Value $Ex[$i]
    $obj += $item
    $i++
}
$obj | Export-Csv -Append -Force  -NoTypeInformation "C:\NotBackedUp\EndpointAudit\Win7machinetest2.csv"
```